# Replace in-line style with new style

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

```
  $string = "<span style='position:absolute'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span> Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation <span style='color:white'>ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo color:white
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</span> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
```

i want to replace and result, only inline not all matching string

```
$string = "<span style='position:relative'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span> Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation <span style='color:black'>ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo color:white
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</span> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
```

Any further advice appreciated. I don't know how you managed to get it working correctly!

Comment: do you even need a regexp for that ?

Comment: @Calimero, I don't have regexp for this

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Simple preg_replace will do the job. You can even use str_replace to do the same.
`echo preg_replace("/:blue/", ":red", $var);`. To make it more secure, adjust your Regex according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure total requirement but hope it will help you. you can use `str_replace` or `preg_replace`. so this is code

**Option1.**

```
$var = "<h2 style='color:blue;'>I want this heading to be blue instead of default red</h2>";

$newphrase = str_replace('color:blue;', 'color:red;', $var);
echo $newphrase;
```

**Option2.**

```
$newphrase = preg_replace("/:blue/", ":red", $var);
echo $newphrase;
```

and both give same output

[image]